# select object in javascript with key's value condition

Tags: javascript, object, key

i have constructor in js:

```
function car (){
    this.name=name;
    this.position=position;
}
```

i created two obj from above constructor and push to array:

```
arr = [ car{name:car1;position:1},
        car{name:car2;position:2} ]
```

and i have another array:

```
map = ["***","car1","***","car2","***"]
```

i want it:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(map[i] !== "***"){ //for example i=1 and map[1] is car1 and i dont know it!
    //i need select car with name = car1 and change this car's position to 10
    }
}
```

i dont want search for "car1". because in my main code when new car (car3) come in car1 position, car1.position must be 0. really in map car's name insert according to cars'position.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select a car with name = car1 and change this car's position
>   to 10

The below should help you

```js
map = ["***", "car1", "***", "car2", "***"];

arr = [{
    name: 'car1',
    position: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'car2',
    position: 2
  }
]


for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (map[i] !== "***") {
    const index = arr.findIndex(x => x.name == map[i]);
    arr[index].position = 10;
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: please see my end line in question. i updated it. i dont want search for car1

Comment: can i do this without any search in array?. can i assign a variable to each car (obj) and call it with this variable?

Comment: when having an array structure you have to find the value in it based on the index here. If it were a object only structure then you could find it in your way buy just passing the key value